# Homotopy type of the realization of the order complex of a topology

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, order-theory, simplicial-complex

For any poset $P$, we can define an abstract simplicial complex $\Delta{P}$ called its *order complex*, whose vertices are the elements of $P$ and whose faces are chains (totally ordered subsets) of $P$.
The geometric realisation $\lvert \Delta{P} \rvert$ of this complex is a topological space. This is described in [1, p. 6].

A topological space $(X,T)$ has a homotopy class $[T]$.

As $T$ is a poset, we may also take the realization of the order complex of $T$, $S = \lvert \Delta(\mathcal{T}) \rvert$, and this has a homotopy class $[S]$.

Are $[S]$ and $[T]$ equal? If not, what is the relationship between them? I'm especially interested in the case when $(X,T)$ is a finite $\mathrm{T}_0$ space.

[1] Wachs, Michelle L. "Poset topology: tools and applications." arXiv preprint math/0602226 (2006). https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602226.pdf

Comment: Your $S$ is path connected. And so these cannot be homotopy equivalent if $X$ is not path connected. Moreover it is a simplicial complex, so it cannot be homotopy equivalent to something that does not have homotopy type of simplicial complex. Like Hawaiian earring.

Comment: What is $[T]$? And if the answer is, 'the homotopy class of $T$', then what do you mean by $T$?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer $T$ is the poset of open sets of the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order complex of any poset $P$ with a greatest or least element $x$ is contractible.  Indeed, $|\Delta P|$ is the cone on $|\Delta (P\setminus\{x\})|$: each simplex in $\Delta(P\setminus \{x
\})$ (i.e., chain in $P\setminus\{x\}$) becomes a cone over that simplex with vertex $x$ (since you can add $x$ as an extra point to the chain), and it can be checked that these glue together to give a cone over the entire space $|\Delta (P\setminus\{x\})|$.  (There are other ways to see this as well; for instance, thinking of $P$ as a category, then $x$ is an initial or terminal object of $P$, and so gives an adjunction between $P$ and the terminal category which becomes a homotopy equivalence after taking nerves.)

So in particular, if $T$ is a topology, then $|\Delta T|$ is always contractible, and in particular is typically not (weakly) homotopy equivalent to the original space $X$.

(What is true is that if $X$ is a finite topological space or more generally an Alexandrov space, then $X$ is canonically weakly homomtopy equivalent to $|\Delta X|$ where $X$ is ordered with the specialization preorder, i.e. the order $x\leq y$ iff $y\in\overline{\{x\}}$.  This is a theorem of McCord which you can find in the paper McCord's paper [*Singular homology groups and homotopy groups of finite topological spaces*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-66-03352-7).)

Comment: Thanks!

I have a related query. Let $S$ be a simplicial complex.

We get a topology from either the Alexandrov topology of its order complex, $A(P(S))$, or its geometric realisation $\mid S \mid$. Are these w.h.e.?

By taking $X = A(P(S))$, your statement says $A(P(S))$ and $|\Delta(W(A(P(S))))|$ are w.h.e., where $W$ is the specialisation preorder.
Wikipedia says $W \circ A$ [is the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology)
And Wach's book says (p.7) $|S|$ and $|\Delta(P(S))|$ are even homeomorphic. 
So we have $|S| = |\Delta(P(S))| \sim A(P(S))$.
Is this right?

Comment: That's correct.